# Why does RandomForestClassifier not support missing values while DecisionTreeClassifier does in scikit-learn 1.3?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, missing-data, decision-tree

In the latest `scikit-learn` release (1.3), it was announced that `DecisionTreeClassifier` now supports missing values. The implementation evaluates splits with missing values going either to the left or right nodes (see [release highlights](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_1_3_0.html#missing-values-support-in-decision-trees)).

However, when I tried using `RandomForestClassifier`, which is an ensemble of `DecisionTreeClassifier`s, it appears that it doesn't support missing values in the same way. I assumed that since `RandomForestClassifier` inherits from `DecisionTreeClassifier`, it would also support missing values.

Here's a simple snippet I used for testing:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X = np.array([0, 1, 6, np.nan]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]

forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
predictions = forest.predict(X)
```

This throws the following error related to the presence of missing values:

> **ValueError**: Input X contains NaN. RandomForestClassifier does not
> accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised
> learning, you might want to consider
> sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which
> accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is
> possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer
> transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a
> list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values

The same code with `DecisionTreeClassifier` works just fine. Can anyone help explain why the `RandomForestClassifier` doesn't support missing values, despite being an ensemble of `DecisionTreeClassifier`s?

Comment: Interesting question, but the only people who can really answer it are the ones who wrote the code -- probably a better way to reach them is through whatever code development platform the project is on. You might be able to reverse-engineer the motivation by looking at the code at the place from which the error originates -- try to find the operation that is protected by the NaN detection. You can also try `git blame` on the code which generates the error to see if the commit log has any comments about the motivation for it.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you for your suggestion. I agree that the developers would likely have the most definitive answer, but I posted the question here as well because I believe the StackOverflow community might provide useful insights or share similar experiences. Also, this discussion could be beneficial to others who come across the same situation in the future. I will consider looking at the codebase and possibly reaching out to the developers on their platform. Thanks again!

Comment: It's being worked on: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/26391.  If I understand the introductory comment, the main reason it wasn't just "turn off the check for missingness pre-fit and let the trees handle it" was a computation-time issue around identifying which features have missing values?

Comment: Thanks, @BenReiniger, for sharing the pull request. Knowing that people are actively working on this improvement is exactly what I was hoping to hear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Ben Reiniger in the comments, people are acutally working on this feature. From `scikit-learn`'s release history I found out that `RandomForestClassifier` and `RandomForestRegressor` will support missing values from version `1.4` on: https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v1.4.html#sklearn-ensemble